# Undefined reference to "function" assembly function

Tags: c, assembly, reference, undefined

This is my first time posting on here, because I'm usually able to find my answers through other questions, but all the other solutions to the question like mine have not worked.

Im using MinGW GCC in Eclipse Mars

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


extern int logicShift(int);
void program1();

int main(void)
{
    program1();

    return 0;
}

void program1()
{
    int num = 0;
    int disp;
    while (num >= 0)
    {
        num += 2;
        disp = logicShift(num); // this is the error right here
        printf ("%d", disp);
    }
}
```

error: `undefined reference to logic shift`

assembly.s file:

```
.global logicShift

logicShift:
    push    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    movl 8(%ebp), %edx
    shll $1, %edx

    movl    %edx, %eax
    pop     %ebp
    ret
```

It is simple assembly. There is no `_`prefix to the functions. I'm pulling hairs out at this point and I need help please.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding the _ prefix?

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: Are you even linking with the object file? :)

Comment: Since you are using MinGW (Windows), that specific `gcc` compiler is expecting that function names on that platform are prepended with an underscore. Modify your code so that you have `.global _logicShift` AND you change your label to `_logicShift:`

Comment: Do not change `logicShift`to `_logicShift` in you _C_ code. Any reference to `logicShift` in the _C_ code will end up looking for a function called `_logicShift` . As long as the assembler code has the underscore added to it, the _C_ code should be able to find it, assuming you are compiling and linking both files together.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried that first and it didn't work.

Comment: @Jester yea I'm not thinking clearly on it. I forgot about having to do this in linux terminal. I'm currently on windows.

Comment: I was clicking build button in Eclipse thinking something would happen -_-'

Comment: Have you added the `.s` file to the project? Does eclipse have some form of build output window where you can see it's assembling and linking your stuff?

Comment: Sounds like they aren't linking them together @Jester.It works here, which means they probably don't have their project set up properly.

Comment: I'd recommend talking to your professor and/or your teacher assistant. They should be able to help you since they understand the environment you should be running in. If you are not allowed to talk to a prof or TA then I question the value of your institution

Comment: I linked it through terminal and it worked. Now when I run it in eclipse the main.c file sees the .S file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are not compiling the them correctly by not including the object file/source file of the assembly code in your compilation command.

Let's say you have the C source in `main.c` and assembly source in `logicshift.S` then, you can compile them to generate an executable called `main` as:

```
gcc main.c logicshift.S -o main
```

Comment: So can  I not compile them in eclipse? Your suggestion looks like what I'd use to compile in a linux terminal.

Comment: Yes. What I said is how you'd on a terminal. In eclipse, probably you need to put bith files in a single project and build them.

Comment: hmm okay, dang I think that'd be inline assembly. My prof. said we can't use inline, so I guess I'm installing Linux again. Thank you!